# Importing specific dataset from excel to Jupiter

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot y=x^2 graph through Jupyter with some scattered data points to compare how does those datapoints correlates with the fromula.

Is anyone know how to draw both formula and data points?

Comment: Could you add to your question so that it is more specific ? In particular, I don't understand if you're asking for a way of loading an excel file or if you're looking for a way of plotting data on a graph

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have an excel dataset of points as it is suggested from the title?

Otherwise you can use matplotlib and numpy to plot both

```
import numpy as np
import matlpotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 200)
y = x**2

x_dataset = ...
y_dataset = ...
#replace "..." depending on how you want to load the data

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y, label="formula")
#replace by plt.plot for line plot
plt.scatter(x_dataset , y_dataset, label="dataset")
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.how()
```